# ASP.NET Core - HTML code block reuse

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on a ASP.NET Core project using Bootstrap 4 and I have some Bootstrap Modals that I want to show in multiple views.

These Modals have some Javascript functions for internal elements, like Buttons and Inputs.

What is the correct approach to load these Modals (with their Javascript) in multiple views?

I figured I'd use PartialViews, but I don't know where to put the Javascript code (I know that putting it in PartialViews is a bad practice).

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate JS file and reference it on the bottom of every page that uses this partial view, so the script does not block the page-rendering.

Alternatively you could create a layout file which contains both the modals HTML and JS, and let your views inherit from this. Although I would advise against this approach due to the composition over inheritance principle.

Answer (score 0):

[Tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro) might be better used for this, here's an example of a bootstrap modal tag helper [ModalTagHelper](https://github.com/dpaquette/TagHelperSamples/blob/master/TagHelperSamples/src/TagHelperSamples.Bootstrap/ModalTagHelper.cs%20ModalTagHelper)

Then if you put this in your _ViewImports file:

```
@using AssemblyNameWithTagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper "*, AssemblyNameWithTagHelpers"
```

You can use a tag helper like this:

```
<modal id="simpleModalFromAnchor" title="Modal Title">
    <modal-body>
        <h4>Something happened</h4>
        <p>Something happened</p>
    </modal-body>
</modal>
```

With the javascript, put it in a separate js file and reference it from each page you use the modal in, better yet, put it in a bundle with other well used components and include it in the bottom of your _Layout file